# Razor table create with nested data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

At the moment I am working on razor view, where I'd like to create a table as follows:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">data</td>
        <td rowspan="5">data</td>
        <td rowspan="5">data</td>
        <td rowspan="5">data</td>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AvailableCodes.Count; i++)
        {
           <td>@Model.AvailableCodes[i]</td>
           @if ((i % 6) == 0)
           {
              </tr><tr>
           }
        }
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But I am getting a parse error (Parser Error Message: The for block is missing a closing "}" character.), at the beginning of the `@for`... a bit clueless why. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell the definition of the @model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in the `for` you don't need to pre-fix with an `@` for the if.

Also in order to ouput un-balanced tags you can use `@:`

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AvailableCodes.Count; i++)
    {
       <td>@Model.AvailableCodes[i]</td>
       if ((i % 6) == 0)
       {
          @:</tr><tr>
       }
    }
```

Comment: Removed the `@` before `if` but still got the same error with the `@for`

Comment: Thank you it is working now, after seeing the edited answer. :)

Comment: @Paxsentry No problem. :)